# How do you force Vue to show falsey attributes using v-bind?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

```html
<button class="navbar__dropdown-toggle" :aria-expanded="active"></button>
```

I am trying to bind `aria-expanded` to the state of a dropdown menu. Unfortunately, when using a screen reader (for the visually impaired), dictation doesn't indicate that it is a non-expanded dropdown menu since falsey attributes are removed.

Is there any way of forcing a falsey attribute to remain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like from the [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_aria-expanded_to_indicate_the_state_of_a_collapsible_element), the value of `aria-expanded` can be true or false. So in your template you can do this.

```
<button class="navbar__dropdown-toggle" :aria-expanded="active ? 'true' : 'false'">expanded</button>
```

Working [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/GEbVZx?editors=1010).

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your boolean has a value, I prefer using `toString()`:

```
<button class="navbar__dropdown-toggle" :aria-expanded="active.toString()"></button>
```

It is short and the intent is perhaps clearer than the other examples.

Answer (score 0):

I'm only assuming `active` is a variable, the most straight-forward answer is `!!active`

Comment: I think it's a Boolean in his case, so not need to cast...Using just 'active' is enough. But this works as well.

Comment: This is not going to work: as the OP stated, falsey attributes are removed